# jQuery now showing the phrased variable value

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

Stuck on the first stage of a big project. I am trying to display the JSON value that I get from URL shown below. It shows the data when I past the URL on the a browser. But when I put the URL in variable and try to show in html it doesn't show the phrased value.(I will delete the app/key one I get the solution.) Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/6Adbu/

```
http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id=72157629130565949&per_page=10&page=1&api_key=ccc93a20a1bb9060fa09041fa8e19fb5&jsoncallback=?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method? This seems to return the data just fine:

```
$.getJSON(apiCall, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/XLwAF/).

**Additional Information**

It seems like you may benefit from a [simple tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/) that explains AJAX in relation to jQuery's [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) methods.

Comment: Never mind, just found out what console is used for. Very powerful tool. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<span>").html(apiCall)
```

`apiCall` is a string (containing the URL).  All you're doing here is setting a span to have the URL as its content.  You need to actually use AJAX to load said URL.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    format: 'json',
    method: 'flickr.photosets.getPhotos',
    photoset_id: '72157629130565949',
    per_page: 10,
    page: 1,
    api_key: 'ccc93a20a1bb9060fa09041fa8e19fb5'
  },
  jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Inside `success`, `data` is the JSON object returned by the API.